# gcc compile error for windows mutex

Tags: c, windows, mutex

Why does the compile give me `error: initializer element is not constant` for a simple creation of a mutex `HANDLE ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);`

I've tried searching but I am totally stumped. No matter what I do it won't compile.I even tried breaking it up:

```
HANDLE ghMutex;
ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);
```

And the compile complain:

```
test.c:90:1: error: conflicting types for 'ghMutex'
test.c:89:8: note: previous declaration of 'ghMutex' was here
 HANDLE ghMutex;
        ^
test.c:90:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);
```

I think there is something wrong with my syntax I just don't know what.

Comment: Could we see the context of that code? Are you trying to do it outside of a function?

Comment: Yes it is outside of a function. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Errors after the first one (especially in the same code) can often be its consequences. Resolve the coflicting type declarations and edit the question if the problem persists.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson was right. The problem was outside the function. I Just started playing with c on windows. Noob mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variables outside of a function, in C, they are part of the `.data` part of the executable, wherein memory is allocated at compile time. Without a constant (which the return variable of `CreateMutex` is not), there is no way to know how much memory to allocate.

To circumvent this, the compiler throws an error, so that you have to put the initialisation in a function so that memory is allocated dynamically at run-time.

This error isn't specific to Mutexes either. The following code would also throw the error:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 5;
int z = x*y;
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

If you're just interested in seeing how would would get around the error, then you could do something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>    

HANDLE ghMutex;

int main(void)
{
    ghMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    CloseHandle(ghMutex);
    return 0;
}
```

This works because `ghMutex` is being allocated at run-time, because it is in a function. As OP stated in a comment: "The problem was [that ghMutex was] outside the function."

Or if you'd like a more in-depth view, the documentation also displays this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx